# What is `uvm_field_* macros for time datatype

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Let say I have a variable of type `time`.

```
class my_class extends uvm_object;
  time my_time;
  int  my_int;
  `uvm_object_utils_begin(my_class)
    `uvm_field_int(my_int, UVM_DEFAULT)
    // ? for time
  `uvm_object_utils_end
endclass
```

As we know, we can use `'uvm_field_int` for `int` data type. 
What is the proper macro for `time` datatype?

Answer (score 1):

Use `uvm_field_int` because as far as SystemVerilog is concerned, `time` is just an alias for `longint`

Better yet, don't use any field macros at all as they are [horribly inefficient](http://verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-7_issue-2/articles/stream/are-ovm-and-uvm-macros-evil-a-cost-benefit-analysis_vh-v7-i2.pdf).